# Google Photos Api "BASE_URL=dv" return not found

Tags: base-url, google-photos, google-photos-api

I use **Google Photos API** to access media items. My response:

```
   {
        "id": "AGj1epWg0cgWQlTxzimRJcC7ZOtL3OGXXcIZGYwJEarHX8iHG4s86ybH1dPI2S0yPIE",
        "productUrl": "https://photos.google.com/lr/photo/AGj1epWg0cgWQlTxzimRJcC7ZOtL3OGXXcIZGYwJEarHX8iHG4s86ybH1dPI2S0yPIE",
        "baseUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lr/AJ_cxPblNAwhstQaQgLvvX25pP0D48nA0s8j4RHS0v-SZiuTL-TIfoD5ScOBBB9TBKLeVDaJBbXQ3-9nz-IhDygQ4IIPWr_U0iGX54tmMjLPRHQVWMcUjZMxeye2M5rkuQp9TZm9oqXyg8juMGkvV6oV_o9uCVFYTmJs6x-cUKJb9vNQoG758dupNio47FXbU7iR4Lvjm18oUxHGmIosyPUSi7vtxKC1j5vUg9Vxvyl24-N2Ed3UavK_FxX2vJ9882PqRC3L7T1GlXIhbHX7uqgPTbi4TuN1v6Tqe5tLDGgHZeh8lqjinBSo_ljvBC9d33F91RPPpDh8JpQsf2NGVXc74TzJVDiSyNxq4hvpodLgyXFQW513Nix1jZg17GqEiE337wyItZ70_zt622uNYFZAirF3k_hYVSGCO5zHq2ZrmNvfxlKt9hhBvZ-1SYZiV9x-8EXjcJaC3q-d1WzmPM78WG8ZpXBtgmPGQTCtah6oljty34IsWiv3t_87EN68ixkFLKlfhU2ydb3kwMjOJdMBMg3niem1nTm1DBJYwmCZLlKnea8LHglE6dXI0ZvihFludXGIeRPNuAZHjRuBVRy8UNSwHWE0s0sI26iSSAnaQ0JpzkF7QFTW6OGOTGPOfAbgdNYj8RXqAbsw2s1gpycRW_dNwPQbvpYRfXXtVHY8_UFp3UHKT_cgBKKpT-WpsrC7UQ5FVqlIkwSnbmM_ih7Z7u0jlKwlatZ_6HzL-79A",
        "mediaMetadata": {
            "creationTime": "2014-02-24T22:05:47Z",
            "width": "1920",
            "height": "1080",
            "video": {
                "status": "READY"
            }
        },
        "filename": "3D Humming Bird.mp4"
    }
```

Follow Google instructions [Google Photos](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items), i used **baseUrl=dv** to download video but it response 404 (not found)

Is this a **google photos** issue or my issue?

Thank.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you make any progress?

Comment: It's fixed, thank google.

Comment: Please let me know, how it is get fixed in your case. I am also getting same issue.